# Why state always changes back to init value when redux rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

State changes back to init value and useEffect run everytime when redux rerender. it looks like component remount after redux state change.

console print hello twice and input box change to empty when i input some text and click Search button.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/es/Button";
import fetch from "cross-fetch";
import actions from "@/actions";
import api from "@/api";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";


const getData = (title, page) => dispatch => {
    dispatch(actions.notice.loading());
    return fetch(api.notice.list({title, page}), {method: 'POST'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(resultBean => {
            dispatch(actions.notice.success(resultBean.data.list))
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch(actions.notice.failure(error));
        });
};

const View = _ => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('hello');
        dispatch(getData(title, 1))
    }, []);
    return (
        <>
            <input onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} value={title} type="text"/>
            <Button onClick={e => dispatch(getData(title, 1))}>Search</Button>
        </>
    )

};


export default View;
```

Comment: What and where is init value? It does not look as if you pull anything from your redux state.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express it clearly. The init value I said refers to the default value of useState. Now the problem has been solved. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not showing the complete logic, in case you `dispatch` action and it triggers `View` parent to render, `View` may re-render or even unmount depending on the condition of its parent.

For `View` not to re-render, you need to memorize it:

```
// default is shallow comparison
export default React.memo(View);
```

For `View` to not to unmount, check its parent logic.

Also, note that using `_` at `const View = _ =>` still allows you to access it like `_.value` which I believe is not what you intended.

Comment: The problem is that the parent component uses react-motion and sets the key property, which will result in forced re-render. thanks for the help